# Keywords cooccurence using OLAP

Tags: keyword, data-warehouse, olap, olap-cube

I have a large set of documents. Each document contains multiple keywords. I would like to create an OLAP cube that calculate the co-occurrence of keywords in this set. is it possible to perform such solution (using olap cube). in this case what would be the attributs of the fact table, the dimensions , the measure and the aggregation function. Also what tool do you suggest.

An example of document : (in JSON form) actually form doesn't matter

[example of document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCzoH.png)

Comment: Do the documents contain unstructured text?  Can you add some example inputs and show us the output you are aiming for?

Comment: documents are structured. I have a lot (1000000 document) and  more than 500000 keyword used.  I want t show  the cooccurence of keywords using olap and a visulization tool.